# Take a dictionary of the following form as an input from the user storing employee details, namely, age, home city and salary

Tags: graph, data-analysis

Question1. Take a dictionary of the following form as an input from the user storing employee details, namely, age, home city and salary:
{'Age': [26, 29, 25, 26, 29, 30, 32, 31, 34, 33, 24, 27, 28], 'Home City': ['Rohtak', 'Aligarh', 'Rajkot', 'Bhilai', 'Rohtak', 'Delhi', 'Faridabad', 'Howrah', 'Delhi', 'Delhi', 'Patna', 'Patna', 'Agra'], 'Salary': [22000, 28000, 18000, 19000, 27000, 25000, 30000, 31000, 34000, 32000, 18000, 24000, 20000]}

```
i. Draw line plot for age vs salary 
ii. Draw scatter plot for age vs salary
iii. Plot histogram for features age and salary
iv. Plot Pie chart for the qualitative attribute city
v. Generate box plots for salary and age
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code you require. However, please note that I didn't understand what you meant by "Plot Pie chart for the qualitative attribute city" and have plotted a pie chart based on my understanding of the question for your reference.

This is just a start, you can customize all of the plot functions based on your needs by passing other arguments which you can easily find online.

```
# Importing necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

# Initializing dictionary to store the user inputs
employee_details = {}

# Accepting comma separated user inputs
# If you wish to accept in different format then change accordingly in the split method
age = list(map(int, input().split(',')))
home_city = list(map(str, input().split(',')))
salary = list(map(int, input().split(',')))

# Forming the dictionary
employee_details['Age'] = age
employee_details['Home City'] = home_city
employee_details['Salary'] = salary

# Converting dictionary into a DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(employee_details)

# Plotting line graph between Age and Salary
df.plot(x = 'Age', y = 'Salary')

# Scatter plot between Age and Salary
df.plot.scatter(x = 'Age', y = 'Salary', title = "Scatter plot between Age and Salary")
plot.show(block = True)

# Histograms for Age and Salary
df.hist()

# Pie Chart for cities
df.groupby(['Home City']).sum().plot(kind = 'pie', y = 'Salary')

# Boxplot for Age and Salary
boxplot = df.boxplot(column = ['Age', 'Salary'])
```